# Extracting two substrings using a regex match

Tags: regex, scala, match

I have a simple regex pattern and a string. The regex pattern is `(\d*)\*(C.*)` and the string is `32*C1234*3`.

I want to extract the values `32` and `C1234*3` from that string using that regex pattern.

I can achieve that in Perl using the following code:

```
my $x = "32*C1234*3"; 
if ( my ($x1, $x2) = $x =~ /(\d*)\*(C.*)/ ) {
    print "x1 = $x1, x2 = $x2\n";
} else {
    print "No match\n";
}
```

The following is my attempt using Scala 2.11:

```
val s = "32*C1234*3"
val re = """(\d*)\*(C.*)""".r
(r findFirstIn s).toList
```

When I run this, I get a single value (and it is the original list followed by empty character) instead of `32` and `C1234*3`. How do I fix the scala code?

Comment: `(re findFirstIn ...`? I don't understand what your problem is, it returns `List(32*C1234*3*)` as expected?

Comment: I am looking for 32 separated by C1234*3 - like in Perl

Comment: You can use [`s.split("[*]", 2)`](http://rextester.com/LWZ75176) to split on the first `*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `findFirstMatchIn`, and then use the `Match` object to select the groups that you need:

```
val m = re.findFirstMatchIn(s).get
val x1 = m.group(1)
val x2 = m.group(2)
```

sets the variables `m`, `x1`, `x2` to:

```
m: scala.util.matching.Regex.Match = 32*C1234*3*
x1: String = 32
x2: String = C1234*3*
```

The `if ...`-part in Perl is replaced by `Option[Match]` in Scala. If you are not sure whether the string actually matches or not, you have to first check whether the result of `findFirstMatchIn` `isEmpty` or not. Alternatively, you can pattern match on the returned `Option`. In the above example, I simply used `get`, because it was obvious that there is a match.

The `findFirstMatchIn` is unanchored, so that the string `"blah|32*C1234*3*"` would return the same match with the same groups.

Answer (score 2):

```
s match {
  case re(a,b) => s"x1 = $a , x2 = $b"
  case _ => "error"
}
```

You have 2 capture groups in the regex pattern so the match pattern has to offer 2 variables to hold the matched values.

---

To get all matched capture groups as a `List[String]` you could do this:

```
re.unapplySeq(s).getOrElse(List.empty)
```

Comment: Just a note: in Perl, the original regex was not anchored, and here, inside `match`  block, it is. However, I think that it should be anchored in the Perl solution, too.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the solution.  Is it possible to get these as a list?  For the solution below (by @Andrey Tyukin), I can do .get.subgroups to obtain a list.